# I don't know why I get the multiple graphs of W versus PT using the attached python code

Tags: python, numpy, odeint

I want to get three graphs (W vs. X, W vs. y, W vs PT). But I can get two proper graphs (W vs. X and W vs. y). Unfortunately, I finally got multiple graphs of W vs PT (green lines). I don't know how to handle it. Anything you could do for me would be highly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def PBR(X, W):
    a = 9.8*10**(-5)
    y = (1-a*W)**0.5
    PH2 = PT0*(1.5-X)*y
    PB = PT0 * X * y
    PT = PT0 * (1 - X)*y
    r = -k * PT * PH2 / (1 + KB*PB + KT *PT)
    dXdW = -r/FT0
    return dXdW

W = np.linspace(0, 10000)
KT = 1.038
KB = 1.39
FT0 = 50
k = 0.00087
PT0 = 12
X0 = 0
a = 9.8*10**(-5)
y = (1-a*W)**0.5
PT = PT0 * (1 - X)*y
X = odeint(PBR, X0, W)
plt.plot(W, PT, 'g', linewidth=0.5)
plt.plot(W, X,'r', linewidth=3.0)
plt.plot(W, y,'b', linewidth=5.0)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLkkK.png)

Comment: You have `PT = PT0 * (1 - X)*y`... but `X` hasn't been set yet. You set `X` on the next line... `X = odeint(PBR, X0, W)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for output like this. If yes - small issue in your script. Look at line marked as #**. You want to multiply with first dimension of X array.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def PBR(X, W):
    a = 9.8*10**(-5)
    y = (1-a*W)**0.5
    PH2 = PT0*(1.5-X)*y
    PB = PT0 * X * y
    PT = PT0 * (1 - X)*y
    r = -k * PT * PH2 / (1 + KB*PB + KT *PT)
    dXdW = -r/FT0
    return dXdW

W = np.linspace(0, 10000)
KT = 1.038
KB = 1.39
FT0 = 50
k = 0.00087
PT0 = 12
X0 = 0
a = 9.8*10**(-5)
y = (1-a*W)**0.5
X = odeint(PBR, X0, W)
PT = PT0 * np.multiply(1 - X[:,0],y) #**
print(PT)
plt.plot(W, PT, 'g', linewidth=0.5)
plt.plot(W, X,'r', linewidth=3.0)
plt.plot(W, y,'b', linewidth=5.0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. But I think this is not the answer I want to get. PT = PT0 * (1-X) * y is correct. PT is dependent on both X and y.

Comment: Do you want corresponding X and Y arrays to be multiplied ? X and Y both are 50 element array.

Comment: Many thanks. I got something wrong. At the moment, I think W is only an independent variable. So W determines X and y, and accordingly, PT is determined by the above-mentioned equation. I am a very beginner at Python. So, I think I know something wrong. Please tell me what I got wrong.

Comment: @Ji Chul How can you using X before it has been assigned?

Comment: Many thanks. This problem is about the chemical process. X is conversion, which is related to PT.

Comment: I change the order of X. Not sure if you are not looking for that. The Green line - does it show expect values for you.

Comment: Lostin is a great help to me. I wanted to multiply with the first dimension of X array. I need to study more about Python. Thanks a million!!